# How can i concatenate data different row from same table in one row?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, concatenation

I have a database name class_routine, where following and row as shown in column are there i want to get all data from row sunday and group it in all in same column, how can i do it ? 
Here is the database and column name and row name
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat  and group by

```
 select day, group_concat(routine)
 from my_table 
 group by day;
```